# Input 2 floats, convert to binary, add them and output the result as a float in c#

Tags: c#

I need to write a code in C# to input two floats, convert them to binary, add the two binary numbers, convert the sum back to float and then give the float output. I have managed to convert the floats into binary. How to proceed further? This is what I have done so far.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter first float: ");
        string FirstString = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter second float: ");
        string SecondString = Console.ReadLine();

        int[] FirstBinary = new int[32];
        int[] SecondBinary = new int[32];

        float FirstFloat = float.Parse(FirstString);
        float SecondFloat = float.Parse(SecondString);

        ToBinary (FirstFloat, ref FirstBinary);
        ToBinary (SecondFloat, ref SecondBinary);

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(FirstBinary[31 - i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(SecondBinary[31 - i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    // Method to convert float to binary
    static void ToBinary(float a, ref int[] number)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            int b = 1;
            number[i] = bytes[0] & b;
            bytes[0] = (byte)(bytes[0] >> 1);
        }

        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++)
        {
            int b = 1;
            number[i] = bytes[1] & b;
            bytes[1] = (byte)(bytes[1] >> 1);
        }

        for (int i = 16; i < 24; i++)
        {
            int b = 1;
            number[i] = bytes[2] & b;
            bytes[2] = (byte)(bytes[2] >> 1);
        }

        for (int i = 24; i < 32; i++)
        {
            int b = 1;
            number[i] = bytes[3] & b;
            bytes[3] = (byte)(bytes[3] >> 1);
        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?
Otherwise it's like you want us to do your work.

Comment: See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic.  First use BitConverter.GetBytes(int) to get bytes.  Then split into exponent, sign and mantisa.  Then you have to make the exponent the same by shifting the manitisa.  One you have bytes it probably easier to take the mantisa and use Bitconvert to make a single inter.

Comment: Side note: `ref` is not needed/unnecessary. Arrays are reference types. Your changes will be seen in the calling method without using `ref`

Answer (score -1):

I have most of the day trying to remember how to do the math and to find a good method for handling the carry out and carry in.  I broke the floating point into a KeyValuePair where the key is the exponent (byte) and the value is the mantissa which I converted to a signed number using the msb of the floating point.  The add became simple which I just had to shift the mantisa value to align the decimal points, add the two mantissa values and then handle the carry out/in.  Finally convert the number back to floating point.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> inputs = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>() {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("1.0", "1.0"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("0.0", "0.0"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("1.0", "-1.0"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("1.0", "-0.5"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("-1.00000", "-0.00001"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("1.5", "-2.5"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("1.5E10", "1.5E10"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("-1.1234", "-1.1234"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("-1.5E-10", "-1.5E-10"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("-1.5", "-1.5"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("-1.5", "-2.5")
            };

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> input in inputs)
            {
                string FirstString = input.Key;
                string SecondString = input.Value;

                float FirstFloat = float.Parse(FirstString);
                float SecondFloat = float.Parse(SecondString);

                KeyValuePair<byte, int> FirstBinary = ToBinary(FirstFloat);
                KeyValuePair<byte, int> SecondBinary = ToBinary(SecondFloat);

                float total = Add(FirstBinary, SecondBinary);
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' + '{1}' = '{2}'", FirstString, SecondString, total.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static KeyValuePair<byte, int> ToBinary(float a)
        {
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);

            byte exponent = (byte)((bytes[3] << 1) | (bytes[2] >> 7));

            int mantisa = ((bytes[2] & 0x7F) << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | bytes[0];

            //add in implied 1 (bit 24) if value is not zero
            if (a != 0) mantisa = mantisa | 0x800000;

            if ((bytes[3] & 0x80) > 0) mantisa = -mantisa;

            return new KeyValuePair<byte, int>(exponent, mantisa);
        }
        static float Add(KeyValuePair<byte, int> FirstBinary, KeyValuePair<byte, int> SecondBinary)
        {
            byte FirstExponent = FirstBinary.Key;
            int FirstMantisa = FirstBinary.Value;

            byte SecondExponent = SecondBinary.Key;
            int SecondMantisa = SecondBinary.Value;

            int mantisa = 0;
            byte exponent = 0;

            //align mantisa using largest exponent and add
            if (FirstExponent >= SecondExponent)
            {
                exponent = FirstExponent;
                mantisa = FirstMantisa + (SecondMantisa >> (FirstExponent - SecondExponent));
            }
            else
            {
                exponent = SecondExponent;
                mantisa = SecondMantisa + (FirstMantisa >> (SecondExponent - FirstExponent));
            }

            byte[] results = new byte[4];


            if (mantisa >= 0)
            {
                if (mantisa != 0)
                {
                    byte carry = (byte)((mantisa >> 23) & 0xFF);
                    //adjust for carry bit 25
                    switch (carry)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            exponent -= 1;
                            mantisa <<= 1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            exponent += 1;
                            mantisa >>= 1;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            exponent += 1;
                            mantisa >>= 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    results[3] = (byte)(exponent >> 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mantisa = -mantisa;
                //adjust for carry bit 25
                byte carry = (byte)((mantisa >> 23) & 0xFF);
                switch (carry)
                {
                    case 0:
                        exponent -= 1;
                        mantisa <<= 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        exponent += 1;
                        mantisa >>= 1;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        exponent += 1;
                        mantisa >>= 1;
                        break;
                }
                results[3] = (byte)(0x80 | (exponent >> 1));
            }
            results[0] = (byte)(mantisa & 0xFF);
            results[1] = (byte)((mantisa >> 8) & 0xFF);
            results[2] = (byte)((byte)((exponent << 7) & 0x80) | ((byte)(mantisa >> 16) & 0x7F));

            float number = BitConverter.ToSingle(results,0);
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```